# Position of search cancel button in Safari 7

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a `input[type=search]` and gave it some `padding`.
In Safari 7 (mavericks at least) the search cancel button gets cutoff. How can I correct this?

I've been trying with the `::-webkit-search-cancel-button` selector and box-sizing, but no luck.

[image]

**jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/hjtkarLc/**

The jsFiddle setup:

CSS

```
input {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin: 1em;
}
input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
#withPadding {
    padding: 0.7em;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="search" value="I'm ok" />
<input type="search" id="withPadding" value="I'm cutoff" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding a `z-index` to the `input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button` and then adjusting the `padding-right` worked for me.

Now it works properly in Chrome AND Safari.

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/celeryclub/u8mhs7aj/1/

Comment: What is the difference between this answer and [Gianmarco's?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29817072/2256325)

Comment: @Sergio Gianmarco's answer doesn't fix the problem. The cancel button is still cut off in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

The solution at your problem might be to apply an extra padding only to the cancel button, something like this:

```
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button{
    padding-right:30px;
}
```

You said that you tried with -webkit-search-cancel-button, but in your jsFiddle is not implemented, so I gave you this hint.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into the same issue. This has to be a Safari bug, as it's localized to the one browser. Even though the icon is cut off, the click area is where you think the icon should be.

Demo of issue - http://codepen.io/cshold/pen/yNWoNo

Things that don't work:

- Adding padding to `input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button` scales the icon in Chrome and doesn't have an effect in Safari.
- Set the same selector as above to `position: relative`. This visually shows the close button, but the click area isn't over top of the icon.

I've submitted a bug report to bugreport.apple.com.